# What's the expected behaviour for CiviCampaign and permissions?

Tags: civicampaign

I'm confused about how to deal with CiviCampaign with different user roles and permissions. I have not found anything in the *[CiviCampaign user documentation](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/campaign/what-is-civicampaign/)*. Our intention is to have two separate permissions (administrator and manager) assigned each to two separate roles.

We expect that *Administer CiviCampaign* permission allows user to create, edit and delete campaigns and *Manage CiviCampaign* permission allows user to only assign activities, contributions, mailings to the campaigns. But in reality both permissions are allowing users to create, edit and delete campaigns.

What do you think about it? This is the expected behaviour? How would you allow a user to assign, for example, a contribution to a campaign without giving him permission to create/edit/delete campaigns?

Comment: Looks like there should be a permission "Access CiviCampaign" that isn't there. See ['CiviCampaign: access CiviCampaign' permission missing](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/983).